# dynamic db2 query in stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, db2, string-concatenation

Hi i had a stored procedure as below,

```
Create  PROCEDURE my_car(
in diesel integer,
out milege integer)
P1: BEGIN

SET START_query = 'SELECT*';
SET FROM_CLAUSE = ' FROM car, diesel';
SET WHERE_CLAUSE = ' WHERE car.c1 = diesel.c2';

IF (diesel =0) THEN            
                SET WHERE_CLAUSE = +WHERE_CLAUSE+'AND car.diesel=0' ;
                ELSE
                SET WHERE_CLAUSE = +WHERE_CLAUSE+' AND car.diesel='+diesel ; 
               END IF;
END P1
```

But its throwing error as below.

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-402, SQLSTATE=42819, SQLERRMC=+, DRIVER=3.52.90
```

and if we use || instead of +
ie.,

```
SET WHERE_CLAUSE = WHERE_CLAUSE || 'AND car.diesel=0' ;
```

then its throwing error as below,

```
DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=||;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.52.90
```

please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DB2, `||` rather than `+` is used for string concatenation.

Also, diesel is a character string and you are comparing it to zero.  If you want diesel to be a 0 or 1 value, you should set its type to integer.  If it needs to be a string, you should compare it to `''` or `'0'` or whatever makes sense.

I'm not sure what you meant by `+V_WHERE_CLAUSE+`, but your code should look something like this:

```
IF (diesel = '0') THEN            
    SET WHERE_CLAUSE = WHERE_CLAUSE || 'AND car.diesel=0';
ELSE
    SET WHERE_CLAUSE = WHERE_CLAUSE || ' AND car.diesel=' || diesel; 
END IF;
```

Or maybe just this:

```
SET WHERE_CLAUSE = WHERE_CLAUSE || ' AND car.diesel=' || diesel;
```

Comment: Hi..thanks for the suggestion dan.. but i tried this too..even then its not working and got error as below..`DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, SQLERRMC=||;FUNCTION, DRIVER=3.52.90
`

Comment: @A Programmer, you also have to define your variables at the top of the procedure like `DECLARE WHERE_CLAUSE CHAR(100);`

Comment: yes yes.. i do declared dan.. i missed in the above code but its there in my real sp.. :-( but still couldn't able to clear

Comment: @AProgrammer, you should post your complete SP (or a simplified complete SP that causes that error) in the question.  Otherwise it will be impossible to tell what is causing that error.